# widgets template system using node.js with dust server side templates

Tags: node.js, widget, express, template-engine, dust.js

I'm trying to create a page with widgets on it using Node.js and Dust as a template engine.
I would like the widgets to be standalone as possible with their own css, js and html.

Which of the follow three method is best? which will be the fastest?

**Option a: using res.render and rendering only once**

```
pseudo code:
   1) call page route (app.get('/', routes.somePage);
   2) load config file (say /views/somePage.cfg) listing all widgets on somePage.
   3) get widget data if needed (say access another server for the data).
   4) build 1 context object and pass to render
   5) call res.render with context containing page data + all widget's data
   5) somePage template will include partials to build page, including widget partials.
```

**Option b: using res.write**

```
pseudo code:
  1) call page route (app.get('/', routes.somePage); 
  2) load config file (say /views/somePage.cfg) listing all widgets on somePage.
  3) use app.render() to render widgets + page (running js to get each widget data) 
  4) use res.write() to build a complete page.
```

**Option c: using helpers**

```
pseudo code:
  1) call page route (app.get('/', routes.somePage);
  2) use app.render()
  3) use custom helper to render different widgets. 
     custom helper will actually grab the data and might use app.render inside to build 
     the widget during render time..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through a few things, I ended up, after discussion on Node.js IRC down the path of doing Option A...It seems it's the correct path, to build one master context and provide it to one template..

I ended up constructing a global context object, and have certain widgets add to it's json.
It works like a charm!